# How to change the text in several labels when a special table view cell is pressed?

Tags: ios, xcode, label, tableview, uitableview

Here are the ViewControllers again.

Here is my ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSDictionary *firstTableView;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *firstTableViewKey;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *norskLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *infinitivLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *presensLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *preteritumLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *perfektumLabel;


@end
```

Here is my ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"


static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SterkeVerb" ofType:@"plist"];

    self.firstTableView = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    self.firstTableViewKey = [[self.firstTableView allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.opaque = NO;
    tableView.backgroundView = nil;


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [self.firstTableViewKey count];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSString *key = self.firstTableViewKey[section];
    NSArray *nameSection = self.firstTableView[key];
    return [nameSection count];

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.firstTableViewKey[section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];

    NSString *key = self.firstTableViewKey[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *nameSection = self.firstTableView[key];

    cell.textLabel.text = nameSection[indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (indexPath.row == 0){

        _norskLabel.text = @"å bake";
        _infinitivLabel.text = @"zu backen";
        _presensLabel.text = @"bäckt/backt";
        _preteritumLabel.text = @"backte";
        _perfektumLabel.text = @"hat gebacken";

}

    else if (indexPath.row == 1){

        _norskLabel.text = @"å motta";
        _infinitivLabel.text = @"zu empfangen";
        _presensLabel.text = @"empfängt";
        _preteritumLabel.text = @"empfing";
        _perfektumLabel.text = @"hat empfangen";
    }
```

}

Ok, so i have my table view devided into sections(A-Z) and when i filled in the code it worked perfectly for the first section. BUT, when i pressed one of the cells in the next section, it showed the same information as the first cell in the first section. WHY?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row == 0){

    _norskLabel.text = @"å bake";
    _infinitivLabel.text = @"zu backen";
    _presensLabel.text = @"bäckt";
    _preteritumLabel.text = @"backte";
    _perfektumLabel.text = @"hat gebacken";

    else if (indexPath.row == 1){

        _norskLabel.text = @"å begynne";
        _infinitivLabel.text = @"zu beginnen";
        _presensLabel.text = @"beginnt";
        _preteritumLabel.text = @"begann";
        _perfektumLabel.text = @"hat begonnen";
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to add some logic to the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, and set the values of your labels there. So, what specifically don't you know how to do?

Comment: I don't know what to write in the tableview:difSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. Should it be something like this? 

    if tableViewRow = NSString@"The_Name_Of_One_Of_The_Rows"

Comment: No, that's totally wrong -- rows don't have names. You use the indexPath passed in to that method to make any decisions based on row number. You really need to read Apple's documentation on UITableView.

Comment: Se what i tried to do, up in the description, any ideas?

Comment: You use the indexPath.row like I said above. If indexPath.row == 0 then some label.text = @"whatever", else if indexPath.row = 1 do something else. Also, don't use stringWithFormat when you already have a string. It should be like this: _norskLabel.text = @"å komme";

Comment: ok, i wrote this and got this small problem i think. Look op in the description. :)

Comment: Put a `}` before `else if` condition to get rid of that `Expected ....`error.

Comment: Ok, so i have my table view devided into sections(A-Z) and when i filled in the information it worked perfectly for the first section. BUT, when i pressed one of the cells in the next section, it jumped back and showed the same information as the first cell in the fisrt section. WHY?

Comment: Because you're not doing anything with indexPath.section. If you have multiple sections in your table, then you need to make use of the section parameter of NSIndexPath as well. It's hard to say how without knowing the structure of your data.

Comment: I added the viewcontrollers again if this is what you want as data? If you please could write me some code that i can use to fix this problem i would love it!

Answer (score 1):

If you set the text in `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` it will just get overwritten when `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called

Inside `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you need to access the data driving the table and change it at its source.

```
NSString *key = self.firstTableViewKey[indexPath.section];
NSArray *nameSection = self.firstTableView[key];

nameSection[indexPath.row] = @"New Value";
```